# Prevent node.js application from exiting once the process is done

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, command-line-interface, console-application

I wrote a really basic nodejs application which look like this:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

const inquirer = require("inquirer");
const chalk = require("chalk");
const figlet = require("figlet");
const shell = require("shelljs");
const fs = require('fs');

//Defining some functions
//~~

//The main part of the code
const run = async function() {
    const answers = await form();
    //other codes
    //~~
}

run();
```

The main purpose of the code is to use the `inquirer` module to ask some question in the console, and then process the answers in the `run()` part. It does perfect job on that. It successfully asks the question and do what it should do with the answers.

However, The process would exit once the answer have been processed. What I want is once the answer have been processed, I want it to answer the same question again, and keep repeating that until I terminate the process manually.

I tried this:

```js
for( ; ; ) {
    run();
}
```

However, It would then answer questions again and again without waiting for answers. Here is how the console looked like:
[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOIJs.png)

I want it to do these:

1. Ask question and wait untill I enter the answer.
2. Process the question (with the codes in `run()`)
3. Once it's done, go back to question 1.

How can I do this?

Comment: `while (true) { await run(); }`

Comment: it would throw an error that await is only valid in async functions.

Comment: @EukkMaru Not since Node v14.8 that [supports top-level await](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v14.8.0/)

Comment: @JeremyThile I'm using node v16.11.0, I kind of oversimplified the error message but the message was something like it should be in an async function or at the top level bodies of modules.

Comment: You can always put my line into an async function and call it. My comment was primarily intended to show that you have to `await` the run() call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing

```
for( ; ; ) {
    run();
}
```

Do this inside `run` function

```
while (true) {
    const answers = await form();
    //other codes
    //~~
}
```

Comment: This worked flawlessly, thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey, @ChrisG, we are not doing the `for` loop. My comment says that we don't need to do `for`.

Comment: Right, sorry, I missed the "instead" :)